# Namespace Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions does not exist in namespace Plugin.Geolocator

Tags: xamarin

I download GeolocatorPlugin-master from GitHub but after I open it in visual studio 2015, I got Namespace Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions does not exist in namespace Plugin.Geolocator problem event I added all files under Geolocator.Plugin.Abstractions.

Please help me out on this problem.

Thanks.

Jason

Comment: you are trying to build the plugin from source?  Or are you trying to use it in a project?

Comment: Yes, just build plugin from the downloaded source.

Comment: checked reference, it show"..\Geolocator.Plugin.Abstractions\Geolocator.Plugin.Abstractions.csproj" rather than Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions, not sure why.

Comment: it builds fine for me

Comment: But the reference of the android and iOS project show "Geolocator.Plugin.Abstractions" but show "namespace Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions" in  Abstractions

Comment: what is reference of Geolocator.Plugin showed on yours

Comment: Here are error I got when I rebuild

Comment: the name of the csproj and the namespaces it uses are completely unrelated.  Have you tried building the Abstractions and Plugin projects first, and then the iOS/Android projects?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Abstractions' does not exist in the namespace 'Plugin.Geolocator' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Geolocator.Plugin.Android

Comment: Yes, I tried, the error showed as above

Comment: some project, the name of the project and namespace are same like project

Comment: DeviceMotion.Plugin.Abstractions

Comment: yes, but there is not a technical requirement, that's just programmer preference

Comment: Can you zip your same Geolocator project and email to me? I will check if  it is build environment related or not.

Comment: No.  I just downloaded it from github and built it.  I've already deleted my copy.

Comment: what other thing should I check to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you get Load failed on project Geolocator.plugin and Geolocator.plugin.Abstractions if do not change project file when you open the Geolocator Tests project?

Comment: Re-loaded with VS 2017 without any problem, all builds are OK now.